# Grails resource tag generating wrong link

Tags: javascript, css, grails, resources

I am working on a project in which different modules are divided in different custom created plugins. As for example-

- AccountingPlugin
- UiPlugin
- Etc....

So like now I have all the UI related stuff inside UiPlugin and I am working on Accounting plugin and I have controllers, services and views of all domains in this plugin only.

I am using [Resource tag](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/resource.html) to get all CSS and JS from the UI plugin and have to use it inside the Accounting plugin like-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${resource(dir: 'assets/css', file: "datepicker.css")}"/>
```

which generates `http://localhost:8080/PROJECT_NAME/plugins/accountancy-plugin-0.1/assets/css/datepicker.css`

but the file is located at- `http://localhost:8080/PROJECT_NAME/plugins/ui-plugin-0.1/assets/css/datepicker.css`

So the problem is that it is looking inside its own resources. How can I make this resource tag to look for resources in a separate(UI) plugin for resources?

Please note: The business logic has been separated from UI and hence we have multiple plugins and a separate UI plugin which is used by all plugins for getting UI and theme. So they cannot be in same plugin.

Comment: Can you try using "contextPath" option provided in resource tag so that is uses relative path

Comment: Thank you Anant yes context path along with `absolute:"true"` worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use context path to provide the plugin path and also use `absolute:"true"` so that the URL starts from project name.

Example-

`${resource(dir: 'assets/css', file: "datepicker.css", contextPath :"plugins/ui-plugin-0.1", absolute:"true" )}`

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${resource(dir: 'assets/css', file: "datepicker.css", contextPath :"plugins/ui-plugin-0.1", absolute:"true" )}"/>`